# What will be the Regex for my required pattern

Tags: java, regex

I have a pattern like -

```
public static void myMethod(int Val , String Val){}
```

so ***public\static\void\myMethod***(int\sVal\s,\sString\sVal)

but if my method have more space than one like public         static it fails.
So how to make a concrete pattern .

Moreover the part inside the bracket is not working, suggest me the way to resolve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\s+` to match one or more occurrence, and `\s*` to match zero or more occurrences. Escape the parentheses so that they are not interpreted as grouping operators.

```
public\s+static\s+void\s+myMethod\s*\(\s*int\s+Val\s*,\s*String\s+Val\s*\)
```

That said, it looks like you are trying to parse Java code with a regular expression. This is not possible since Java (like the [infamous [X]HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)) is not a regular language.

Comment: I would just change the + with a * before the comma

Comment: Actually I just want to read the methods from java , I got JavaParser for the same , so now I am doing the assembling job of all parameters , return type and method name to make a complete method and then to revalidate.

Comment: Thanks , that worked :) , can you suggest me the importance of a* as when I changed it I found it was accepting only 1 space between the word blocks.

Answer (score 1):

use `\s+` instead

Comment: `\s*` allows no whitespace, and `privatestaticvoid` is not legit

Comment: @Ben so true, I was typing too fast :P

Answer (score 1):

A few things, but you are on the right track. Replace your `\s` with `\s+` to indicate 1 or more whitespace characters.

Also, your parens are not working because they are reserved regex characters. You must escape them to have them be literally interpreted

```
/public\s+static\s+void\s+myMethod\s*\(\s*int\s+Val\s*,\s*String\s+Val\s*\)/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the "one or more" modifier (`+`) to match multiple occurrences:

```
public\s+static\s+void\s+myMethod...
```